# Multiple authentication providers in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm starting a new project, using ASP.NET MVC 3, and one requirement is to support multiple authentication providers, i.e. Live ID, Google, Facebook, etc. I've looked at companies that provide such a service, but ideally I need a free solution.

Does anyone know of a free service?

If not, the only other solution is to develop something similar to support the providers I'm interest in. Has anyone implemented such a thing? If so, can someone provide any suggestions, articles, guidence, etc, to help with this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an open source library that supports all the sites out there. You may take a look at [OpenId](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/) for those that support this protocol. For FaceBook you could use the [Graph API](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Would you consider Windows Identity Foundation as a possibility?

Answer (score 0):

[Jainrain Engage](http://www.janrain.com/products/engage/pricing) is free for their basic accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst not free the [Windows Azure Access Control Service](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/tour/access-control/) provides just that
You use [Windows Identity Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa570351) in your website to point at the ACS, and configure the ACS with Live ID, Google, Yahoo ID and/or Facebook (as well as potentially any other STS)